# Query by attributes in pre-queried records (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

There is a table `MEETINGPARTICIPANT` as below, PK is `ORGID`, `MEETINGID` and `PARTICIPANTID`

```
Name               Null?    Type          
------------------ -------- ------------- 
ORGID              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
MEETINGID          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32) 
PARTICIPANTID      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32) 
EMPLOYEEID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32) 
DISPLAYNAME                 VARCHAR2(128) 
EMAIL                       VARCHAR2(128) 
JOINTIME           NOT NULL DATE          
LEAVETIME          NOT NULL DATE          
CREATETIME         NOT NULL DATE          
LASTMODIFIEDTIME   NOT NULL DATE
```

Step 1, list records by `ORGID`, `MEETINGID` and `EMPLOYEEID`, get a record list.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MEETINGPARTICIPANT
WHERE
    ORGID=#{orgId}
    AND MEETINGID=#{meetingId}
    AND EMPLOYEEID=#{employeeId}
```

Step 2, iterate each record of step 1, search again by `EMAIL` and `DISPLAYNAME` of step 1, merge to a large record list

```
for (each record in step 1) {

    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        MEETINGPARTICIPANT
    WHERE
        ORGID=#{orgId}
        AND MEETINGID=#{meetingId}
        AND EMAIL=#{record.email} AND DISPLAYNAME=#{record.displayName}

    Merge searched records to mergedRecords
}
```

Step 3, return `mergedRecords`

Question is, how to merge the SQLs in step 1 and 2 into a single SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the SQL below works. The `NVL(EMAIL, ' ')` and `NVL(DISPLAYNAME, ' ')` are going to handle records whose EMAIL or DISPLAYNAME are null.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MEETINGPARTICIPANT
WHERE
    ORGID=#{orgId}
    AND MEETINGID=#{meetingId}
    AND (NVL(EMAIL, ' '), NVL(DISPLAYNAME, ' ')) IN (
        SELECT
            NVL(EMAIL, ' '), NVL(DISPLAYNAME, ' ')
        FROM
            MEETINGPARTICIPANT
        WHERE
            ORGID=#{orgId}
            AND MEETINGID=#{meetingId}
            AND EMPLOYEEID=#{employeeId}
    )
```